# Issue with pthreads, unsure where error is

Tags: c, pthreads

(Correct code added for completeness of problem) I have a program written to find a Floyd-Warshall shortest path matrix from all points in graph (entered as a matrix) to all other points in graph.  Code posted below.  My issue has something to do with the pthreads / LowestTerm function I believe.  For small matrices, the program works just fine.  However, for large matrices and large numbers of threads (8ish being large) I am getting a Segmentation Fault error with no other information provided.  Compiling shows no problem.  Anyone see anything out of place with the code the way it is written?  Could it be that the threads are all trying to access the matrix at the same time, even though they are dedicated to specific rows of the matrix?  Thanks for any help and advice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int n, **C, **D, printthread;                   /* Variable declarations */
pthread_t *threads;
pthread_cond_t condprint;
pthread_mutex_t mutexprint;
long thread, threadcount;

printthread = 0;

void *LowestTerm(void* rank);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i, j;                       /* Variable declarations */
    char filename[50];

    threadcount = atoi(argv[1]);
    threads = malloc (threadcount * sizeof(pthread_t));

    printf("Enter filename: ");             /* User enters filename for directed graph values */
    scanf("%s", filename);

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {                   /* Check whether file exists or not */
        printf("File does not exist");
        return 1;
    }

    fscanf(fp, "%d", &n);                   /* Obtain size of matrix */

    C = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));          /* Allocate memory for matrix arrays */
    D = (int **)malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {               /* Allocate matrices into 2D arrays */
        C[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        D[i] = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {               /* Read matrix from file into C array */
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &C[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Cost Adjacency Matrix:\n");         /* Print cost adjacency matrix */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", C[i][j]);
        }
        printf(" \n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {               /* Copy matrix from C array into D array */
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            D[i][j] = C[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf("Distance matrix:\n");               /* Print Distance matrix label */



    for (thread = 0; thread < threadcount; thread++) {  /* Create threads for making and printing distance matrix */
        pthread_create(&threads[thread], NULL, LowestTerm, (void*) thread);
    }
    for (thread = 0; thread < threadcount; thread++) {  /* Join threads back together */
        pthread_join(threads[thread], NULL);
    }

    pthread_cond_destroy (&condprint);
    pthread_mutex_destroy (&mutexprint);
    free(threads);
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}


void *LowestTerm(void* rank) {

    int i, j, k;                        /* Variable declarations */
    long mythread = (long) rank;

    int istart = ((int)mythread * n) / (int)threadcount;    /* Create matrix row start and finish parameters for each thread */
    int ifinish = ((((int)mythread + 1) * n) / (int)threadcount);

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {               /* Find shortest path for each value in each row for each of designated thread's rows */
        for (i = istart; i < ifinish; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (D[i][j] > D[i][k] + D[k][j]) {
                    D[i][j] = D[i][k] + D[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexprint);           /* Print distance matrix portion for each thread */
    while (printthread != mythread) {
        pthread_cond_wait (&condprint, &mutexprint);
    }
    for (i = istart; i < ifinish; i++) {
        printf("Thread %d: ", mythread);
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%d ", D[i][j]);
        }
        printf(" \n");
    }
    printthread++;
    pthread_cond_broadcast (&condprint);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexprint);


    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from this line:

```
int i, j, k, n, totaln, **C, **D;
```

Since the i, j, and k counters are declared in global scope they are shared by all of the threads.

If a thread is context switched while inside the inner loop, another thread can increment one of these counters past the end of the array. When the original thread wakes it will try to read past the end of the array, which is undefined behavior and can cause a segfault.

You can fix this by limiting the scope of the counter variables to the LowestTerm function. In fact, the only variables that need to be defined in the global scope are **D, n, and threadcount; and n and threadcount don't really need to be shared, they could instead be passed as arguments to LowestTerm.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 0):

Both `j` and `k` loop from `0` to `n`, so the term `D[k][j]` could be any element in the matrix.

So although you're only writing to specific rows (indexed by `i`), every thread is reading every part of the matrix while other threads are modifying the matrix.